# Unable to export CLASSPATH for localhost on Ansible on Linux Redhat

Tags: java, linux, ansible, environment-variables, classpath

I get the below error while executing the shell command on ansible localhost

```
$  java utils.dbping ORACLE_THIN <dbhost>:<dbport>:<dbname>
Error: Could not find or load main class utils.dbping
```

In order, to resolve this error i set the classpath like below:

```
export CLASSPATH=/web/playbooks/automation/libraries/com.bea.core.datasource6.jar
```

With this the `java utils.dbping` command works fine.

I try the same command in ansible on localhost as below:

```
 47        - name: Check DB connection with DBPING
 48          shell: "java utils.dbping ORACLE_THIN <dbhost>:<dbport>:<dbname>"
 49          environment:
 50            CLASSPATH: "/web/playbooks/automation/libraries/com.bea.core.datasource6.jar"
 51            PATH: "/web/jdk1.8.0_291/bin"
 52          delegate_to: localhost
```

But i get the below error indicating that the CLASSPATH was not set correctly.

```
02:57:43 failed: [remotehost7 -> localhost] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "java utils.dbping", "delta": "0:00:00.078752", "end": "2021-07-12 17:27:43.616820", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2021-07-12 17:27:43.538068", "stderr": "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver\n\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)\n\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)\n\tat sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)\n\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)\n\tat java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)\n\tat java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)\n\tat utils.dbping.main(dbping.java:282)", "stderr_lines": ["java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", "\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)", "\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)", "\tat sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)", "\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)", "\tat java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)", "\tat java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)", "\tat utils.dbping.main(dbping.java:282)"], "stdout": "\nError encountered:", "stdout_lines": ["", "Error encountered:"]}
```

I even tried `CLASSPATH: "/web/playbooks/automation/libraries/com.bea.core.datasource6.jar:.:"` but that too did not help.

I also tried `java -cp` option but still no luck.

I prefer to mention the CLASSPATH in ansible rather than in shell prompt along with ansible command.

Answer (score 1):

I thought of deleting this post as the answer had nothing to do with ansible. I will anyways post it and delete the post if suggested.

The error clearly indicated that the class file was missing i.e a jar was missing in the `CLASSPATH`. I added it and now it works.

```
 50            CLASSPATH: /web/playbooks/automation/libraries/com.bea.core.datasource6.jar:/web/playbooks/autom    ation/libraries/ojdbc6.jar
```